# How to secure web services when authentication is done at client side (frontend)

Tags: django, api, authentication, authorization, saml-2.0

I have web application which structure is as-

- webapi : django web services [NOT REST] no security implemented
- frontend : Angular2. authentication implemented via SAML
- Database : Mongodb

Can you please suggest best way to secure webapi, as currently anyone can access web services who has server[api] url

It will be big help if you suggest the authentication and authorization flow because I am totally stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an `/authentication` on your API which accepts `Basic authentication`. Make sure you do that over HTTPS. Username and password will be collected by your Angular app and sent back to `/authentication`. If the user authenticates, return a session token, for example [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (check `pyjwt`).

All the following communications between the front and back should contain the token, which is issued only if the user authenticated. The token is inclued in the request headers and specifically in `Authororization` header using the `Bearer` schema:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

A JWT contains the username so you can use that on each future request. Furthermore, you are not required to keep record of the issued JWT since each one is self-contained and can have predetermined expiration data.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my scenario, angular app is authenticating over saml with ADFS credentials, Once user gets authenticated it will receive saml response token . In this scenario, till now angular app hasn't requested web api service. Can you make me understand as I am new to this, What parameter should I use for /authenticate method as I am not allowed send or store user credentials on web service api.